# Symfony config component and Doctrine dbal

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, config, symfony-components

Via composer i installed doctrine dbal and symfony2 config component

```
"require":{
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "2.4.*",
    "symfony/filesystem": "2.4.*",
    "symfony/config": "2.4.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.4"
}
```

I autoload them via

```
 require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'
```

Then code goes like this

```
 use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
 $container = new ContainerBuilder();
 $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/app/config/'));
 $loader->load('global.yml');

 $config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
 $connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'mydb',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'qwerty',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
 );
 $conn = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
```

Question is how to load Doctrine DBAL configuration from global.yml file ?

Comment: you can write a service for that, and load service on yml file

Comment: I dont know how to do this atm, but thank you for your idea, i ll try to do so!

Comment: Found http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html