# Symfony config component and service for Doctrine DBAL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-components

This is a continuation of [Symfony config component and Doctrine dbal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398258/symfony-config-component-and-doctrine-dbal)

I am trying to create service for doctrine now  like this:

```
<?php

namespace Localhost\Service;

use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;

class Doctrine
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $doctrineLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine');
        $doctrineLoader->register();

        $doctrineConfig = new Configuration();
        $doctrineParams = [
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'dbname' => 'levelup',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => 'toor',
        ];
        return DriverManager::getConnection($doctrineParams, $doctrineConfig);
    }
}
```

And then i am trying to call it like

```
$doctrineConnection = $sysContainer->get('doctrine');

$sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM `thoughts`';
$queryResult = $doctrineConnection->query($sqlQuery)->fetch();
```

But i am getting error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Localhost\Service\Doctrine::query()
```

Why, without service it's working perfectly?
p.s. If you have better ideas or advices how to rewrite this code to fit symfony service structure, i would be happy to hear them.

Comment: __construct never returns anything so trying to have it return a connection object will not work.  You are trying to build a factory.  You want to replace the __construct with a static method Doctrine::create().  Then look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html to see how to use a factory.

Comment: @Cerad, thank you for your help, can you please describe in details what you mean with `You want to replace the __construct with a static method Doctrine::create().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Doctrine
{
    // Just rename __construct to create and make it static
    static function create()
    {
        $doctrineLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine');
        $doctrineLoader->register();

        $doctrineConfig = new Configuration();
        $doctrineParams = [
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'dbname' => 'levelup',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => 'toor',
        ];
        return DriverManager::getConnection($doctrineParams, $doctrineConfig);
    }
}
```

Then in services.yml file:

```
doctrine:
    class: Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
    factory_class:  'Localhost\Service\Doctrine'
    factory_method: 'create'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm and now i have a material to study!