# DBAL connection as service throws error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I followed [**this SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426444/symfony-config-component-and-service-for-doctrine-dbal/22427451#22427451) to build my DBAL connection as service.

I have the following configuration:

In my service class file "Doctrine.php", I have

```
<?php
namespace Acme\BookBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;


class Doctrine
{
    // Just rename __construct to create and make it static
    static function create(){
        $doctrineLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine');
        $doctrineLoader->register();

        $doctrineConfig = new Configuration();
        $doctrineParams = [
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'dbname' => 'book_enterprise_hub',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
        ];
        return DriverManager::getConnection($doctrineParams, $doctrineConfig);
    }

}
?>
```

In my services.yml, I have the following:

```
parameters:
    dbal_connection: book_enterprise_hub

services:
    doctrine:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
        factory_class:  'Acme\BookBundle\Services\Doctrine'
        factory_method: 'create'
```

In my CompanyController.php, I have the following code,

```
<?php
use Acme\BookBundle\Services\Doctrine;

class CompanyController extends Controller
{
    public function createAction()
    {
        $con = $this->get('doctrine');
        $sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE book_info (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, label TEXT, created_on DATETIME) ENGINE = INNODB";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

When calling this line **$con->prepare($sqlQuery)**,

I get the following error,

**Attempted to call method "prepare" on class "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry" in C:\wamp\www\symfony\src\Acme\BookBundle\Controller\CompanyController.php**

Actually, I am using factory method for getting DBAL connection as service but kept getting this error. Can I write parameters in service.yml as given above or I should write in parameters.yml only? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See my detailed answer below, I solved this using **DriverManager** as DBAL connection handle for the database. Using other methods, as suggested in other posts, did not work for me. So, I post my own answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I read service container very carefully in symfony doc and utilzed an answer given by someone in a different post and got the following config to work for me:

In my **services.yml**,

```
parameters:
    dbal_connection: book_enterprise_hub
    bookservice.class:   Acme\BookBundle\Services\BookService

services:
    bookservice:
        class:      %bookservice.class%
```

** Note, I am not passing arguments here, because when passed, it threw this error "**You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine.dbal.book_enterprise_hub"**, so, I pass this DB information in **bookservice** __construct method.".

In my service file **BookService.php**,

```
<?php
namespace Acme\BookBundle\Services;

//1st method (not working)
//use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

//second method
use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;

class BookService
{
    private $connection;

    //1st method (not working)
    // public function __construct(Connection $connection)  {
    //     $this->connection = $connection;
    // }


    //second method
    public function __construct()  {
        $doctrineLoader = new ClassLoader('BookService');
        $doctrineLoader->register();

        $doctrineConfig = new Configuration();
        $doctrineParams = array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'dbname' => 'book_enterprise_hub',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
        );
        $this->connection = DriverManager::getConnection($doctrineParams, $doctrineConfig);
    }


    public function createTable($tableName){

        $sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE ".$tableName." (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, label TEXT, created_on DATETIME) ENGINE = INNODB";
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sqlQuery);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In my **BookController.php**, I could access the DBAL as service like this,

```
<?php
use Acme\BookBundle\Services\BookService;

class BookController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Creates a new Book entity.
     *
     */
    public function createAction()
    {
        $tableName = $form->get('entityId')->getData();
        $obj = $this->get('bookservice');
        if($obj->createTable($tableName) == true){
            // some code.
        }
    }
}
```

With this config, "**You have requested a non-existent service. 500 Internal Server Error - ServiceNotFoundException**" is resolved.

Comment: Good job! Building your own service to handle table creation is definitely the right approach.

Comment: Thank you, Haig but the documentation in symfony was not clear about DBAL setup as service. I was quite disappointed but anyway got a way to solve it. It took me almost 2 days to find out the right way.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I have plenty of my own gripes with Symfony documentation. What I find extremely useful as a resource is the API documentation - http://api.symfony.com.

Answer (score 2):

The OP of question you linked is not using Symfony2 Framework, he is asking how to set up Doctrine service with Symfony Configuration component.

As you are using Symfony2, you don't need to do any of that, you can just do:

```
<?php
use Acme\BookBundle\Services\Doctrine;

class CompanyController extends Controller
{
    public function createAction()
    {
        $con = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.default_connection');
        $sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE book_info (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, label TEXT, created_on DATETIME) ENGINE = INNODB";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

As for the error. It is thrown because there is already a service registered into Symfony called `doctrine` and it resolves to an instance of [ManagerRegistry](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/class-Doctrine.Common.Persistence.ManagerRegistry.html) by default.

That said, I don't think it's a good idea to use connection in controller directly.

Comment: hi Igor, thanks for your suggestion. I was totally confused and not able to setup simple DBAL connection. I tried as you said, I get this error **You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine.dbal.book_enterprise_hub". Did you mean this: "doctrine.dbal.book_enterprise_connection**; **500 Internal Server Error - ServiceNotFoundException** I get this exception.

Comment: What does this mean "a non-existent service "doctrine.dbal.book_enterprise_hub" in this error? Should I register it as service?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to configure doctrine as a service in Symfony. It is already available as a service and it can be retrieved from the service container within a controller: `$this->getDoctrine()` or `$this->get('some-service-id')`. You can see what services are available and their corresponding IDs by running the following console command:

```
php app/console container:debug
```

You can also add the `--show-private` option to that command to see private services as well. Generally speaking, I think the most common doctrine service will be the doctrine Entity Manager (`doctrine.orm.entity_manager`), which you can use to store/retrieve/remove objects in your database, and entity repositories for querying data, which you can setup as services individually for injection into other services.

If you're simply trying to construct your tables (aka entities) for your application, you don't need to/shouldn't run direct SQL queries in the controller. What you should do is:

1) Create your doctrine `Entity` classes in the Entity directory of your bundle. For example:

```
// src/Acme/BookBundle/Entity/BookInfo.php
namespace Acme\BookBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="book_info")
 */
class BookInfo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    ...
}
```

2) Run the `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` console command. This will instruct doctrine to create your entity tables in the database that you setup for your project (connection information should be in `app/config/parameters.yml`).

As an example, to store a BookInfo object ***$myBookInfo*** in the database would then be as simple as doing this in your controller:

```
...
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($myBookInfo);
$em->flush;
...
```

Of course this is a very basic example just to help you understand.

Read [Databases and Doctrine in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) for more specifics.

Comment: Thank you Haig for your detailed answers. I am already using entity manager for 2 seperate databases. For the 3rd one, I need to create tables dynamically with varied columns in it while running application. For this, I could not use entity manager because the **doctrine:schema:update** command is not working properly when specifying selected tables, because as I told you, EM is not suitable with this doctrine update command because columns along with tables are dynamic.

Comment: **comment continuation:**  This is the reason I am using DBAL without EM. Anyway, whenever I use this command "**$this->get('some-service-id')**" as you suggested, I get service error (**You have requested a non-existent service**), I don't know if this is a bug or something else.